# Why are there 2 GPU options on my M1 MAX?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have the blender 3.1 build that now supports Metal. When I select the "Metal" option, there are 2 options (seen in pic below). Why are there 2 options, and which one should I choose?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is whether or not to use the Metal GPU on the M1.  The second option is whether to use the CPU on the M1.

As far as I know, the preliminary support from Apple works with both.

Edit in response to a comment:

[M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) is a System-on-Chip (SOC) meaning that the CPU and GPU are both on the same chip, along with other things.

[Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) is Apple's name for their software layer that other software (like the Blender Program) are supposed to use when they access a GPU on an Apple device.

So the "Metal" button is telling Blender to use the Metal software and the first checkbox is telling the metal software whether to use the hardware GPU while the second checkbox is telling metal whether to use the hardware CPU.

Comment: I've always used the CPU on the M1, so now why (if the second is CPU) Metal accelerated? Is there Metal on the CPU? (Sorry, I don't know that much about computer hardware)

Comment: M1 is a System-on-Chip (SOC) meaning that the CPU and GPU are both on the same chip, along with other things.  Metal is Apple's name for their software layer that other users (like the Blender Program) are supposed to use when they access a GPU on an Apple device.  So the "Metal" button is telling Blender to use the Metal software and the first checkbox is telling the metal software whether to use the hardware GPU while the second checkbox is telling metal whether to use the hardware CPU.